# Netsuite Scheduled script stuck on pending status

Tags: scheduled-tasks, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created scheduled script to generate and print pdf from wave record. When multiple roles, multiple users prints multiple waves prints simultaneously, some prints process simultaneously as 10 deployments created, but some stuck on pending status until previous prints completes the processing. Is there any solution? I will appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending status means the job is awaiting processing slots in the scheduled jobs queue.  This queue includes jobs from Scheduled Scripts, Map/Reduce Scripts, and *I think* scheduled workflows also.  From all these jobs, there is a limit to how many can be processed simultaneously.  That limit is set by your licensing - check with your NetSuite account manager what it is for your account.

When there are more jobs in the queue than can be processed simultaneously, the remaining jobs will be pending until the first jobs finish.  As each job completes, another can start.  For something like generating and printing a PDF I would expect that to happen pretty quickly.

To answer the question as to whether there's a solution; the only direct solution would be to purchase additional SuiteCloud Processing licenses to allow more simultaneous jobs to be processed. Whether that's really needed for your use case is another question.

Comment: Actually there is a another high priority script. I think due to this my script is delaying to enter in queue

Comment: When I print 3 waves at a time, then wave 2 and wave 3 remains pending until wave 1 completes execution. I have created 10 deployments but then also script is not executing parellaly.

Comment: My script is executing parallely in sandbox but one by one in production. I am not understanding the exact reason.

Comment: *I have created 10 deployments...* - that's ok, you need to have deployments free for the script to be added to the queue.  However, that *doesn't* mean that they will process immediately.  Check if you have other scheduled tasks like map/reduce scripts (which you need to check in a separate page) which are taking up processing slots.

Comment: My script is executing one by one even when no other schedule/map reduce is executing.